# Finding quotient and remainder

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Find the quotient and remainder when $f(x)$ = $3x^3 − 2x^2 + 5x − 7$ is
divided by $x + 2$.

I found quotient to be $3x^2 - 8x -11$ with remainder 15. I'm sure the remainder is correct but not sure about the quotient, am I right?

Comment: Is it hard to check?

Comment: You should check the step where a $-8x^2+5x$ appears.  I believe a sign error occurred there.

Answer (score 2):

When you factor polynomials like this over, you should end up with
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=p(x)(x+2)+r(x)
\end{equation*}
Where $r(x)$ is a polynomial with degree less than $deg(x+2)$. In this case that gives you a constant. This allows you to plug in $-2$ for $x$ to discover the remainder!

\begin{equation*}
f(-2)=-49
\end{equation*}

It looks like you need to tweak your remainder. Have you heard of synthetic division? This video might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZoMz1Cy1T4

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the remainder and the quotient, if you are right you should have
$$
3x^3 - 2x^2 + 5x - 7 = (3x^2 -8x - 11)(x + 2) + 15.
$$
Do you?